# Update route and redux state data at same time

Tags: reactjs

I have an app that has user profiles. On the user profile there are a list of friends, and when clicking on a friend it should take you to that other user profile.

Currently, when I click to navigate to the other profile (through redux-router Link) it updates the URL but does not update the profile or render the new route.

Here is a simplified code snippet, I've taken out a lot of code for simplicity sake. There are some more layers underneath but the problem happens at the top layer in my Profile Container. If I can get the userId prop to update for ProfileSections then everything will propagate through.

```
class Profile extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    const { userId } = this.props.params

    if (userId) { this.props.getUser(userId) }
  }

  render() {
    return <ProfileSections userId={user.id} />
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ user }) => {
  return { user }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getUser })(Profile);
```

As you can see, what happens is that I am running the `getUser` action on `componentWillMount`, which will happen only once and is the reason the route changes but the profile data does not update.

When I change it to another lifecycle hook like `componentWillUpdate` to run the getUser action, I get in an endless loop of requests because it will keep updating the state and then update component.

I've also tried using the `onEnter` hook supplied by react-router on Route component but it doesn't fire when navigating from one profile to another since it's the same route, so that won't work.

I believe I'm thinking about this in the wrong way and am looking for some guidance on how I could handle this situation of navigating from one profile to another while the data is stored in the redux store.

Comment: you can have a look at https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux if it fits your use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I would suggest you approach this in the following way:

```
class Profile extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const { userId } = this.props.params

    if (userId) { 
      // This is the initial fetch for your first user.
      this.fetchUserData(userId)
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { userId } = this.props.params
    const { userId: nextUserId } = nextProps.params

    if (nextUserId && nextUserId !== userId) {
      // This will refetch if the user ID changes.
      this.fetchUserData(nextUserId)
    }
  }

  fetchUserData(userId) {
    this.props.getUser(userId) 
  }

  render() {
    const { user } = this.props

    return <ProfileSections userId={user.id} />
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ user }) => {
  return { user }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getUser })(Profile);
```

Note that I have it set up so in the `componentWillMount` lifecycle method, you make the request for the initial `userId`. The code in the `componentWillReceiveProps` method checks to see if a new user ID has been received (which will happen when you navigate to a different profile) and re-fetches the data if so.

You may consider using `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` instead of `componentWillMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps` respectively for the `fetchUserData` calls, but it could depend on your use case.